# Allowing remote connections to SQL Express

Tags: firewall, sql

On Windows 2008 Server R2, I installed SQL Server Express 2014 successfully and enabled TCP/IP on the default port (1433) and also added an inbound firewall rule to add port 1433. The database option to allow remote connections is already turned on. I also restarted the server after making the changes.

I mostly followed this video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5UkHYNwUtCo

I am not able to from the Windows 10 client machine. I can ping the server name from the Windows 10 client. When I open SQL Server Management Studio, and enter the servername or ip or servername,1433 or ip,1433 (different combinations) in the right format, I get the following error:

A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - The wait operation timed out.) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 258)

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Try to telnet the server from your local machine on port 1433. Check whether port 1433 is open in server windows firewall if not then add a rule and open port 1433 on server or check if there is any hardware firewall which is not allowing port 1433 through it.